# How to set jetty port xsbt plugin 1.0.0-M7

Tags: scala, xsbt

I have just upgraded from 0.9.0 to 1.0.0-M7 of the xsbt web plugin. However my build.scala now no longer compiles. I am setting the jetty port by doing the following:

```
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.PluginKeys.port
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.WebPlugin.{container, webSettings}

... // in my Build object
  def Conf = config("container")
  def jettyPort = 8081
```

But after the upgrade the compiler can no longer find the imports giving me the error below. I have been unable to find an updated sample of the correct way to set this port.

Thanks
Des

```
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.PluginKeys.port
[error]                        ^
[error] .../project/build.scala:9: object xsbtwebplugin is not a member of package com.earldouglas
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The package has changed to com.earldouglas.xwp
2. To get the settings for jetty, you have to call jetty(...). This method exists in the com.earldouglas.xwp.XwpPlugin object.

See the [readme](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#configure-jetty-to-run-on-port-9090).

Comment: Yes I have already seen that. But what is the equivalent syntax if you are using build.scala rather than build.sbt? That is not documented anywhere as far as I can find. jetty(port = 9090) does not compile for example.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to try it out right now, but normally you should have to add jetty(port...) to your projects settings with ++.